# Establish for which constants c the following functions are densities.

Tags: probability

Establish for which constants k the following functions are densities.

$f(x) = k(5-x)$ on $0 \leq x \leq 7$ and $0$ otherwise

So basically

$$1 = \int_{0}^{7} k(5-x)dx = k(5x - \frac{1}{2}x^2)\bigg|_{0}^{7} = \frac{21}{2}k$$

Thus, $k = 2/21$.

Would this be right? My concern is with the intervals. What if it were

$0 < x < 7$ or $0 \leq x < 7$ or $0 < x \leq 7$. How do they differ and would their answer be different?

Answer (score 1):

A single point makes no difference to the value of the integral, hence the function will be a pdf on all those intervals

There is an issue however - in order for it to be a pdf, you need it to be non-negative and your function clearly is negative for $x=6$.